# UITableView NSInternalInconsistencyException Error Thrown; Two animations for one cell

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView that I want to edit inside of a UITableViewController. This code is from the method that I call to edit the tableView.

```
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    NSMutableArray *things = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

    self.storedCell = [things objectAtIndex: path.row];

    [things removeObjectAtIndex: path.row];

    for ( int i = 0; i < [things count]; i++) {
        Task *mo = (Task *)[things objectAtIndex: i];
        [mo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: i] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
    }
    [things release]; things = nil;
    self.newPath = path;

    [self.managedObjectContext save: nil]; 
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

and this is the error that is thrown:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt to create two animations for cell'
```

Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Comment: Yes the reload call worked, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of deleting and then inserting the same row, if that's what you want to do, just reload it:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

However, it looks like you should just be deleting the row so you should probably just remove the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` line.  (Of course, you didn't post all of the code so I don't know for sure....)